# Angular2: How to load NPM modules using system.js?

Tags: angular

I am experimenting practice apps with Angular2 and wanted to know way to include npm modules in Angular2 app.

For example, I am trying to use [Angular-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-uuid) npm module and could not find proper way to achieve this. The module files are downloaded in `/node_modules` directory and also added to `package.json` and I am using `system.js`.

1) One of the option was to use `sytem.import("angular-uuid")`, however I still could not get module identified. 
2) Do we have to still use `<script src=" "></script>`
3) Can we import as `import * as angular-uuid from "angular-uuid";`

What is the recommended way of adding `npm modules`?

Comment: Did you try using JSPM?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

angular2 has its own UUID module if you want to use:

```
npm install angular2-uuid --save
```

Then in your component you can import it as :

```
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid';
```

To generate UUIDs:

```
let uuid = UUID.UUID();
console.log(uuid);
```

Hope this helps.